# Community flags a closed question as commentless after a comment from an off-topic closure

Tags: bug, flags, vote-to-close, moderator-tools, beta-phase

When a moderator closes a question on a beta site, if there is no comment on the question, Community raises a flag:

> Please explain the nature of this closed question via a comment

This happens even when the question was closed as off-topic with a custom comment. Obviously, in that case, there is a comment — the flag indicator even says so. So Community should not raise this flag.

[image: screenshot]